# How many distinct isomorphism types are there of an unlabeled two vertex graph? With labels?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, category-theory, graph-isomorphism

How many isomorphisms are there of unlabeled 2 vertex graphs, and how many of labeled 2 vertex graphs? Loops are allowed.

I know this is trivial but I suspect there're 4 unlabeled, no loops, one edge; no edge, two loops; one loop, one edge; one loop no edge;
Would labeling halve this?

Labeling refers to the vertices.

Comment: What does "how many isomorphisms?" mean? Between most pairs of graphs, there are no isomorphisms, because they are not isomorphic at all. If the graphs are isomorphic, there can be one isomorphism or many - but it depends on which pair of graphs you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

The number of loops can be zero, one, or two; that's $3$ possibilities.

The number of edges can be zero, or one; that's $2$ possibilities.

And each of the first $3$ possibilities can be combined with each of the last $2$ possibilities, making $3 \times 2 = 6$ different isomorphism types in total. So, you forgot some.

Comment: and with labels?

Comment: How do you define "labelled graph"? Is it just vertices being labelled? Or just edges? Or both? If you could clarify this by editing your post, I could address it.

Comment: labeled vertices

Comment: I realized something I need to ask: Are you allowing at most one loop to be attached to each vertex? Because otherwise my answer is wrong: if one may attach an arbitrarily large number of loops to each vertex then there are infinitely many isomorphism types.

Comment: Good question. I'll have to ask my instructor. Let's say there is at most one loop a vertex, how would labels change the isomorphic types?